# How to upload a CSV file in FastAPI and convert it into JSON?

Tags: python, csv, upload, fastapi, csvtojson

I am trying to upload my `.csv` file to my FastAPI server, then convert it into JSON and return it to the client. However, when I try to process it directly (without storing it somewhere), I get this error:

```
Error : FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory : "testdata.csv"
```

This is my FastAPI code:

````
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    data = {}    
    with open(file.filename,encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader:             
            key = rows['No']
            data[key] = rows    
    return {data}```
````

Comment: What is the output of `os.getcwd()`, and is it the same as the location of `testdata.csv`?

Comment: Actually I am Directly uploading file in UI and I am not storing anywhere so when I use is getcwd() command I do get 200 response code but response body [ null ]

Answer (score 18):

Below are given various options on how to convert the uploaded `.csv` file into JSON. The following `.csv` sample file is used in the examples below.

**data.csv**

```
Id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
```

### Option 1

The [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) method can accept as a `file` argument [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) as well. FastAPI's [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) uses Python's [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object (for more info on that, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804)). You can access that through the `.file` attribute of the `UploadFile` object. However, since FastAPI/Starlette opens the file in `bytes` mode, if you passed it directly to the `csv.DictReader()` method, you would get an error, i.e., `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes`. Hence, you could use [`codecs.iterdecode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.iterdecode) (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869804/17865804)) that uses an incremental decoder to iteratively decode the input provided by the *iterator* (in this case from `bytes` to `str`). Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import csv
import codecs

app = FastAPI()
    
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(file.file, 'utf-8'))
    data = {}
    for rows in csvReader:             
        key = rows['Id']  # Assuming a column named 'Id' to be the primary key
        data[key] = rows  
    
    file.file.close()
    return data
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "1": {
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20",
    "height": "62",
    "weight": "120.6"
  },
  "2": {
    "Id": "2",
    "name": "Freddie",
    "age": "21",
    "height": "74",
    "weight": "190.6"
  },
  "3": {
    "Id": "3",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "17",
    "height": "68",
    "weight": "120.0"
  }
}
```

In case you wanted to **return a `list` of dictionaries** instead, you could use the below. Since the below would require the `file` to be `open` while returning the results, hence preventing the server from properly closing the file (by calling `file.file.close()`) when it's done, one could use [`BackgroundTasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) (which run *after* returning a response) to close the file:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, BackgroundTasks
import csv
import codecs

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(file.file, 'utf-8'))
    background_tasks.add_task(file.file.close)
    return list(csvReader)
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20",
    "height": "62",
    "weight": "120.6"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "name": "Freddie",
    "age": "21",
    "height": "74",
    "weight": "190.6"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "17",
    "height": "68",
    "weight": "120.0"
  }
]
```

### Option 2

Another solution would be to read the byte data of the uploaded file— using `contents = file.file.read()` (for `async` read/write see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804))—then convert the bytes into string, and finally load them into an in-memory text buffer (i.e., [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)), as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607230/17865804), which can be passed to `csv.DictReader()`. Example below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import csv
from io import StringIO

app = FastAPI()
    
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    data = {}
    contents = file.file.read()
    buffer = StringIO(contents.decode('utf-8'))
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(buffer)
    for row in csvReader:  
        key = row['Id']  # Assuming a column named 'Id' to be the primary key
        data[key] = row  
    
    buffer.close()
    file.file.close()
    return data
```

### Option 3

To approach the problem in your way—i.e., using a filepath to read the csv file, instead of using the file contents directly or the file-like object, as described earler—you can copy the file contents into a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which unlike [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) that `UploadFile` provides, "has a visible name in the file system" that "can be used to open the file" (again, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804) out for more info on that). Below is a working example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os
import csv

app = FastAPI()
    
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    data = {}
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    try:
        try:
            contents = file.file.read()
            with temp as f:
                f.write(contents);
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
        finally:
            file.file.close()
        
        with open(temp.name,'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
            for rows in csvReader:             
                key = rows['Id']  # Assuming a column named 'Id' to be the primary key
                data[key] = rows
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error processing the file"}
    finally:
        #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
        os.remove(temp.name)  # Delete the file
    
    return data
```

### Option 4

You could also write the bytes from the uploaded file to a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) stream, which you could then convert into a Pandas DataFrame. Next, using the [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804)), you could convert the dataframe into a dictionary and return it—which, FastAPI, behind the scenes, will convert into JSON-compatible data, using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/), and finally, serialise the data and return a [`JSONResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#jsonresponse) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details). As a faster alternative, you could use the [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method and return a custom `Response` directly, as described in Option 1 (**Update 2**) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()
    
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = file.file.read()
    buffer = BytesIO(contents)
    df = pd.read_csv(buffer)
    buffer.close()
    file.file.close()
    return df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

**Note**: If the file is too big and is taking up all of the memory and/or is taking too much time to process and/or return the results, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719352/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804)

Comment: The `file.read()` must be `file.file.read()`

Comment: @snowmanstark All `UploadFile` methods "_call the corresponding file methods underneath (using the internal `SpooledTemporaryFile`)_". Please have a look at the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile)

Comment: I was wrong in saying that "The `file.read()` must be `file.file.read()` ". If we want to convert 
"""
contents = await file.read()
decoded = contents.decode()
buffer = StringIO(decoded)
"""
then it would be `buffer = StringIO(file.file.read().decode())`

Comment: You **shouldn't** change _asynchronous_ reading of the contents to _synchrnonous_, unless you have decided to declare your route with `def`, not `async def`. Doing so (while the route is declared with `async def`) would result in blocking the entire server, until that operation is completed. Please have a look at the following references to understand the concept of `async/await`: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601373/17865804), [3](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I get your point!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the `Error : FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory : "testdata.csv"` is because you are trying to read a file that is not stored locally.

If you want to read the file this way you should save the uploaded file before proceeding:

```py
async def upload(uploaded_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # save csv to local dir
    csv_name = uploaded_file.filename
    csv_path = 'path_to/csv_dir/'
    file_path = os.path.join(csv_path, csv_name)
    with open(file_path, mode='wb+') as f:
        f.write(uploaded_file.file.read())

    # read csv and convert to json
    data = {}
    with open(file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader:             
            key = rows['No']
            data[key] = rows    
    return {data}
```

Comment: But I was trying to do it directly like when file is uploaded in UI directly it should have been fetched and converted to JSON format and later I'll save that JSOn data to MySQL database but my code is fetching just name of uploaded file and not the actual file itself

Comment: Have you tried `content = await file.read()` directly after the function definition? After that you can use the `file.content_type` property to get the file extension to determine the processing method.

Answer (score 0):

The `file` in the async function `upload()` is already open and you can fetch characters from it directly, there's no need to open it again. Also  in FastAPI the class [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/) is actually derived from standard library [`tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile), which cannot be accessed by specifying path of the temporary file.

For example , if you use CPython and  read the value of `file.filename` in the `upload()` in the Unix-like system, it returns a number instead of a well-formed path, because any instance of the class `SpooledTemporaryFile` will create a file descriptor (at some point when current stored data exceeds `max_size`) and simply return the file descriptor (should be a number in Unix) on accessing `SpooledTemporaryFile.filename`

Comment: So how should I use this Spooled temporaryfile I am very much confused