# How to handle user uploaded Image files in a FastAPI app?

Tags: python, api, csv, fastapi

I am writing an API for an AI model. This AI model gets images from a folder named `input`, does the process on the image or images and outputs the result in another folder named `output` in CSV format, which is then converted into JSON and returned to the user. This API is going to be used in a website, which will be used by many users in the future.

This is the code that I wrote so far and I know it's not a good practice, for example what if 100 users want to use this feature concurrently?

The AI model is a script in `main.py` file.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import pandas as pd
import csv 
import json 



IMAGEDIR = "inputs/"
app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/upload_image/")
async def upload_image(img: UploadFile = File(...)):
    img.filename = f"new.jpg"
    contents = await img.read()

    with open(f"{IMAGEDIR}{img.filename}", "wb") as f:
        f.write(contents)
    
    result = {}
    try:
        import main
        result = csv_to_json('outputs/Results/Results_1.csv')
        return result
    except:
        raise('Server Error')
        result = {'error': 'server error'}
    


def csv_to_json(csvFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)


    return jsonArray
```

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: I might be missing something, but what problem? Doesn't your code work?

Comment: It works just fine. but I don't know how it handles multiple users requests. I mean how to make such API work on larger scale. This code gets an image and name it new.jpg. what will happen if for example 3 users use this API at the same time. I don't know about these scenarios. or if fastapi handles it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a CSV file in FastAPI and convert it into JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617121/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-in-fastapi-and-convert-it-into-json)

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: [Don't optimize prematuraly](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). But if you want to test it, read about load testing.

Comment: In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804), please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) as well, which explains the difference between using `async def` and `def` endpoints, as well as provides solutions when you need to run synchronous blocking operations inside `async def` endpoints.

Comment: Please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `blocking operations` inside an `async function`, which causes the event loop (created by FastApi) get blocked and be unable to handle more requests. Using libraries like [aiofile](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles/) might improve the performance; Although I'm not sure how much improvement you can get, since the Disk i/o operations might be the bottleneck then.